# Disable P.O. Box entry on Paypal Express?

Tags: paypal, address, validation, shipping-address, paypal-express

Is it possible to disallow orders shipping to PO Boxes when a customer is checking out using Paypal Express?

Answer (score 0):

When you use PayPal Express, you review the shipping information after you've redirected back from the PayPal website. You confirm your delivery address and select a shipping method. Only after you've done this does the payment get finally set and authorised.

This 'Review' page is still 100% subject to your own shipping rules, so that if you have a PO Box restriction on any other Payment Method, then this will also apply here.

If you'd like more information on PO Box restrictions, there's a number of modules out there that will allow this kind of restriction on your shipping methods.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/no-p-o-box-allowed-in-billing-or-shipping-address.html

Answer (score 0):

Still works if you can you know where to put the validations.

https://www.fontis.com.au/blog/preventing-po-box-shipping-addresses

What's Paypal say if you call them? I know some individuals can get around this. the issue we have is Free Shipping is choosen and it's a heavy item.So we have to call them quickly to let them know we cannot ship.